# How to get specific tag's value from SOAP response in Karate DSL?

Tags: soap, karate

I am trying to validate the "success" message from the below SOAP response. But it is returning "#notpresent.

How can we locate the specific inner attribute like messageDate or messageID or Status?

Below is the SOAP Response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <PatientNotificationResponse messageDate="2022-02-02T02:20:20.222Z" messageID="StageValidation" service="patientnotify" status="success" version="11.0"/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I also tried navigating to the specific attribute but nothing returned:

```
* def response = /Envelope/Body/PatientNotificationRequest/status == "success"
* print response
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
* match //PatientNotificationResponse/@status == 'success'
```

Do spend some time looking at Karate examples of XPath usage.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter. It worked and will surely go through the Karate documentation.